# ASP.NET Identity make Email/Password token never expires

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I know this doesn't make a lot of sense, but my client request that the tokens to be made never expires.

I did some research and found out that I can specify the duration for `TokenLifespan`, so my first thought is to make the duration super long thus making the tokens seem to be "never expire"

```
var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = 
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"))
                {
                    TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2160)
                };
        }
```

However, regardless what I set for the `TokenLifespan`, the token will still expire 3 days later.

I did a test, say 1 day or 2, they work just fine, but for some reasons it cannot get past 3 days. What exactly is happening here?

Comment: If the user's security stamp changes it will invalidate the token. Have you verified this wasnt happening?

Comment: I did not actually verify it, but it shouldn't be changing. I generated the token on Friday and over the weekend, no one has touched the system (I have a test environment)

Answer (score -1):

take a look here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/762428/ASP-NET-MVC-and-Identity-Understanding-the-Basics

You shouldn't make the token persistent you should define that on the login part

```
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(
            new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, 
            userIdentity, 
            rememberBrowserIdentity);
```

Comment: Can you please explain further? What do you mean by "shouldn't make token persistent"?

Comment: @C.J. look at the link i provided. 

You don't have to make the dataProtectionProvider token persistent you can add the IsPersistent property when you call "AuthenticationManager.SignIn"

Comment: Sorry, I'm still very confused, how does "SignIn" have to do with PasswordResetToken?

Comment: It doesn't. The DataProtectionProvider is for password resets and such. Nothing to do with the Signin expiration.

Comment: So why is @Owain asking me to add the IsPersistent property in the "AuthenticationManager.SignIn"?